# Efficient way to find an available GCP VM configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM in the `us-west` region. I generally want `n1` machines with 2-16 CPUs and 1 GPU. Within this, I don't particularly care about the specifics (GPU type, exact number of CPUs/amount of RAM, etc.) I frequently struggle to find an available machine type (when I try to start the machine, I get an error informing me that requested configuration is not available).

Currently, my approach is to randomly try different configurations via the GUI on console.cloud.google.com until one works. This is time-consuming (can take 30 minutes or more) and frustrating. Is there a better way? I am considering writing a bash script that will use the Cloud SDK to systematically try different configurations until one works, but this seems hacky, and I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. The ideal solution would allow me to start a machine with just one or a few actions. I don't mind waiting a while, it would just be nice to be able to have an automated way to find an available machine, rather than manually going through until I chance upon something that's available.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no easy way to check the available resources on every location. As the resources were used by different people or customers. One way to ensure availability of resources is [creating a reservation.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview#consuming_reserved_instances)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below code for automatically trying to start a VM with different configurations. I'm very open to other possible solutions to this, but posting here in case it's useful for someone else.

```
'''
Utils for dealing with Google Cloud Platform (GCP)
Source of below code: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#python
'''

from __future__ import annotations
from itertools import product
import sys
from typing import Any
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

from google.api_core.extended_operation import ExtendedOperation
from google.api_core.exceptions import ServiceUnavailable, BadRequest
from google.cloud import compute_v1


def wait_for_extended_operation(
    operation: ExtendedOperation, verbose_name: str = "operation", timeout: int = 300
) -> Any:
    """
    Waits for the extended (long-running) operation to complete.

    If the operation is successful, it will return its result.
    If the operation ends with an error, an exception will be raised.
    If there were any warnings during the execution of the operation
    they will be printed to sys.stderr.

    Args:
        operation: a long-running operation you want to wait on.
        verbose_name: (optional) a more verbose name of the operation,
            used only during error and warning reporting.
        timeout: how long (in seconds) to wait for operation to finish.
            If None, wait indefinitely.

    Returns:
        Whatever the operation.result() returns.

    Raises:
        This method will raise the exception received from `operation.exception()`
        or RuntimeError if there is no exception set, but there is an `error_code`
        set for the `operation`.

        In case of an operation taking longer than `timeout` seconds to complete,
        a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` will be raised.
    """
    result = operation.result(timeout=timeout)

    if operation.error_code:
        print(
            f"Error during {verbose_name}: [Code: {operation.error_code}]: {operation.error_message}",
            file=sys.stderr,
            flush=True,
        )
        print(f"Operation ID: {operation.name}", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
        raise operation.exception() or RuntimeError(operation.error_message)

    if operation.warnings:
        print(f"Warnings during {verbose_name}:\n", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
        for warning in operation.warnings:
            print(f" - {warning.code}: {warning.message}", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)

    return result


def change_machine_type_and_start(
    project_id: str, zone: str, instance_name: str, new_machine_type: str,
    num_gpus: int, gpu_type: str
) -> None:
    """
    Changes the machine type of VM. The VM needs to be in the 'TERMINATED' state for this operation to be successful.

    Args:
        project_id: project ID or project number of the Cloud project you want to use.
        zone: name of the zone your instance belongs to.
        instance_name: name of the VM you want to modify.
        new_machine_type: the new machine type you want to use for the VM.
            For example: `e2-standard-8`, `e2-custom-4-2048` or `m1-ultramem-40`
            More about machine types: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-resource
    """
    client = compute_v1.InstancesClient()
    instance = client.get(project=project_id, zone=zone, instance=instance_name)

    if instance.status != compute_v1.Instance.Status.TERMINATED.name:
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"Only machines in TERMINATED state can have their machine type changed. "
            f"{instance.name} is in {instance.status}({instance.status_message}) state."
        )

    machine_type = compute_v1.InstancesSetMachineTypeRequest()
    machine_type.machine_type = (
        f"projects/{project_id}/zones/{zone}/machineTypes/{new_machine_type}"
    )
    
    operation = client.set_machine_type(
        project=project_id,
        zone=zone,
        instance=instance_name,
        instances_set_machine_type_request_resource=machine_type,
    )

    wait_for_extended_operation(operation, "changing machine type")

    # this section from here:
    # https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.instances.InstancesClient
    if num_gpus > 0:
        accelerator_config = compute_v1.AcceleratorConfig()
        accelerator_config.accelerator_count = num_gpus
        accelerator_config.accelerator_type = (
            f'projects/{project_id}/zones/{zone}/acceleratorTypes/{gpu_type}'
        )
        accelerator_request = compute_v1.InstancesSetMachineResourcesRequest()
        accelerator_request.guest_accelerators = [accelerator_config]
        # accelerator_request = {
        #     'accelerator_count': num_gpus,
        #     'accelerator_type': f'projects/{project_id}/zones/{zone}/acceleratorTypes/{gpu_type}'
        # }
        accelerators = compute_v1.SetMachineResourcesInstanceRequest(
            project=project_id,
            zone=zone,
            instance=instance_name
        )
        accelerators.instances_set_machine_resources_request_resource = accelerator_request

        operation = client.set_machine_resources(request=accelerators)
        wait_for_extended_operation(operation, 'changing gpus')

    # try to start the VM
    operation = client.start(
        project=project_id, zone=zone, instance=instance_name
    )
    wait_for_extended_operation(operation, 'instance starting')


def change_machine_type_and_start_loop(
    project_id: str, zone: str, instance_name: str, new_machine_types: list,
    gpu_nums: list, gpu_types: list
):
    running = False
    i = 1
    while not running:
        pbar = tqdm()
        combs = product(new_machine_types, gpu_types, gpu_nums)
        for new_machine_type, gpu_type, num_gpus in combs:
            machine_desc = f'{new_machine_type} with {num_gpus} {gpu_type}'
            try:
                pbar.set_description(f'Trying {machine_desc}... (attempt {i})')
                # print(f'Trying {machine_desc}... (attempt {i})')
                change_machine_type_and_start(
                    project_id, zone, instance_name, new_machine_type, num_gpus, 
                    gpu_type
                )
                running = True
                break
            except (ServiceUnavailable, BadRequest):
                i += 1
                
    print('Instance started!')
    print(f'Config: {machine_desc}')
```

The code can be run with something like the follwing:

```
project_id = 'my-project'
zone = 'us-west1-b'
instance_name = 'my-vm'
new_machine_types = [f'n1-standard-{n}' for n in [8, 16, 32]]
num_gpus = [1]
gpu_types = [f'nvidia-tesla-{g}' for g in ['t4', 'v100','p100']]

change_machine_type_and_start_loop(
    project_id, zone, instance_name, new_machine_types, num_gpus, gpu_types
)
```